# How do I Encrypt a File

Tags: c#, encryption

I try to encrypt a file with Microsoft's `File.Encrypt(filename)` function. After trying to encrypt the file, I always get

> System.IO.IOException "The Request is Not Supported"

My Code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string toencrypt = Console.ReadLine();
   File.Encrypt(toencrypt);
}
```

This is not the full code, I am using it to encrypt files with special codes so they are not easily editable.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `File.Encrypt` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Encrypt_System_String_); some quotes: "_Both the Encrypt method and the Decrypt method use the cryptographic service provider (CSP) installed on the computer_", "_This method is not available on all versions of Windows. For example, it is not available on Home editions._" and "_The current file system must be formatted as NTFS._"

Comment: Permissions, or you don't have NTFS partition?

Comment: Is there a method that works on all computers without Installing anything and that works on every file system?

Comment: This wouldn't works on an non-NTFS partition as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, you might want to peruse the documentation of the `System.Security.Cryptography` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=netframework-4.7.2, also see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptography-model). Choose an encryption scheme/cipher according to your needs, and if needed google for some tutorial that shows you how to utilize the classes in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace...